# How to write a single bit in a file in Java

Tags: java, file, byte, bit

I would like to know if it's possible to write in a file bit by bit. I have sevaral sequences of bits written as a String

`String bitString = "00101101"; // as an example for just one sequence`

And when I try to write this sequence in a file (txt), it doesn't give me the expected result. My file weighs 8 bytes and I would like it weighs only 1 byte (8 bits : my `00101101`).

So my question is : What's the simplest way to write directly as binary in a file from a string or integer ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I develop my problem :

I have an input string that I read from an input file (any text file so I don't know what string will it be) let's take the example of "*Hello World*".

I am using an algorithm of text compression that I created which use the HuffMan Tree Method. It Returns me a sequence of bits that correspond to my text (this is for the explanation, we don't really need this part) for my example, it gives me the following bits sequence : `00001100 11011011 10000101 11101011` which is lighter than the original binary value of my text (11 bytes for the original against 4 bytes with the compression).

What I would like to do is to write this new sequence in an output file and I want each character to be considered as a single bit (or each 8 characters to be considered as a byte) and as a result, the output file should be lighter than my input file.

But the problem is that when I try to write my new sequence, each character is considered as a byte instead of a bit and the output file is heavier than the input one.

I already tried a lot of things such as FileOutputStream, OutputStream,
Convert my String into bytes, Convert into integer, ...

Here is what I'm trying to do :

```
String optimizedString = "00001100110110111000010111101011";  // size always multiple of 8
byte outputByte = 0;
try (OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("textCompressed.txt")) {           
    for (int i = 0; i < optimizedString.length(); ++i) {
        if (optimizedString.charAt(i) == '1') {
            outputByte = (byte) (outputByte << 1 + 1); // add 1 to the sequence
        } else {
            outputByte = (byte) (outputByte << 1 + 0); // add 0 to the sequence
        }

        if ((i+1) % 8 == 0) { // print each byte in the output file
            fos.write(outputByte);
            outputByte = 0; // reset the byte for the next sequence
        }
     }
}
```

But as a result, outputByte is always 0.

I hope I've been clearer

Comment: Technically you can't write less than a disk sector (usually about 1k to 4k bytes).  The file system is just pretending that the 4k sector is only 8 bytes long.

Comment: Are you saying you have text containing `0` and `1` characters, and you want to translate the bits they represent into data?  You could just read eight characters at a time, call `Integer.parseInt(substring, 2)`, and pass the parsed int value to `OutputStream.write`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write less than a byte, and the reason why your file is 8 bytes is because you wrote 8 characters to it. If you had a `Writer` and did the following:

```
writer.write(0b00101101)
```

it would do what you want. Basically, it's using binary notation to define an `int` and writing this int as a single character, instead of writing it as a string of the binary representation.

Comment: Why a Writer and not an OutputStream?  Writers encode text;  an OutputStreamWriter using the UTF-16 charset would write two bytes for that one value.  An OutputStream, on the other hand, would always write a single byte.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I saw this method but what if I don't know the bit sequence ? I mean is there is a dynamic way to do this ? Because I know I can't do writer.write(0b + bitString) where bitString is my bits sequence

Comment: @VGR I guess I'm not that deep on the subtleties between the two, I've always been using them pretty much interchangeably. I can make a few tests when I have time to check my answer.

Comment: @CédricCosson if you want to write a byte at some point you're gonna have to know what byte it is. What's your input? How is it represented, and who gives it to you?

Comment: A Writer writes characters, not individual bytes.  Unicode has hundreds of thousands of codepoints; most of them are values which require more than eight bits.  If writing to a byte-based resource like a file or socket, each character must be *encoded* into bytes, using a Charset like UTF-8.  Any bytes with their high bit set will be encoded as multiple bytes in UTF-8.  An OutputStream, on the other hand, writes bytes directly and does not do any encoding of the values given to it (usually).